# How to install chef-solo for vagrant with knife

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I am on a MAC OSX 10.8, I know this quest should be googled but I am still a bit confused.

I am working on a vagrant deployment that should use chef-solo, but when I went to the opscode site, chef installers are separated into chef-client and chef-server, if I install chef client would that install the chef-solo? I can not find any installer for chef-solo on the net too. Also when installing chef would that also install the knife?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

#### chef-solo is a part of Chef Client

See the package contents from Ubuntu 13.04

```sh
vagrant@devops:~$ dpkg -L chef | grep chef-solo
/opt/chef/bin/chef-solo
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/bin/chef-solo
```

#### Install Chef Client

Option 1

Shell script => [`install.sh`](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh)
which detects OS and use OS specific packages to install chef

Option 2

Use [`vagrant-omnibus`](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) to take care of Chef Client installation within the guest.

Install the plugin

```sh
vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus
```

Add the block in `Vagrantfile`, for example

```js
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "raring64"
  config.vm.hostname = "devops#{rand(01..99)}.vagrant.vm"

  # Use vagrant-omnibus to install chef client
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  # Enable Berkshelf via vagrant-berkshelf
  # config.berkshelf.enabled = true
```

Spin up the VM and it'll take care of the chef client installation.

> NOTE: Chef Client is still available as a gem but OS specific (self-contained) packages are recommended, just make it easier to install and maintain.